# MySQL Get max TimeStamp and associated key

Tags: mysql, subquery, union-all

I have 2 tables, `Posts` and `Replies`. They both contain the `PostID`, and a `TimeStamp` of when the data was inserted.

In a single query, I'd like to know, the most recent entry, out of both tables, and the associated `PostID` for that entry.

I know in MSSQL I can do this with subqueries, as below;

```
SELECT
    PostID,
    MAX(TimeStamp) as newTimeStamp
FROM (
    SELECT
        PostID as PostID
        ,TimeStamp as TimeStamp
    FROM
        Posts
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        PostID as PostID
        ,TimeStamp as TimeStamp
    FROM
        Replies
)
GROUP BY
    PostID
ORDER BY
    newTimeStamp DESC
```

I've been going at this for 20 minutes now - and I know its a simple solution.

To clarify, `PostID` is a PK of `Posts` and `PostID` is a FK of `Replies`. I want to know, the most recent activity on all `PostID`, in descending order of TimeStamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT 
   , Posts.PostID
   , Posts.TimeStamp as LatestPost
   , Replies.TimeStamp as LatestReply
   , COALESCE(Replies.TimeStamp, Posts.TimeStamp) as LastActivity
FROM
    Posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Replies
        ON
    Replies.PostID = Posts.PostID
WHERE 
    Posts.TimeStamp = 
        (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp)
         From Posts sub 
         WHERE sub.PostID = Posts.PostID ) 
  AND
    (Replies.TimeStamp is NULL  
     OR Replies.TimeStamp =
        (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp)
         FROM Replies sub
         WHERE sub.PostID = Posts.PostID
        )
    )
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

Comment: Hi dennis,This still returns multiple results for a single `PostID`.

Comment: Hi, @oliversarfas: I have added a NOT NULL clause to the above, but you should not need it..  It should return exactly two results, assuming unique TimeStamp in each table.  One for Posts and one for Replies.  (That is, unless either Posts or Replies is empty).  If TimeStamp is not unique, we need more information to discern which is latest.

Comment: @oliversarfas Sorry, I had somehow omitted Group By.  I usually test these things, but did not have the tools present today.

Comment: not a problem - I'd added that myself instinctively anyway

Comment: @oliversarfas I have edited again since Group By is not what you want.

Comment: This now returns two rows for a single PostID.

Comment: @oliversarfas, please show example output, best you can within the limits of a comment.

Comment: apologies on the formatting. **Headers**. Table output is csv with semi colon delim. 
**type,PostID,TimeStamp** 
Replies,2,06/08/2015 12:15;Posts,2,05/08/2015 16:50;

Comment: Added a LIMIT clause.  Original request was a little ambiguous on this point.  For further discussion, please move this to Chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85300/discussion-between-dennis-and-oliversarfas).